# Formato con decimales

Tags: php

Tengo varios vectores como arrays
y de estos vectores solo a 1 deseo ponerle el estado con decimales y separador de miles.

Cómo hacerlo sin que me ponga el formato a las demás columnas?

```
$Vec_PARTEVBLE[20][0]="f_creacion";
$Vec_PARTEVBLE[20][1]="";
$Vec_PARTEVBLE[20][2]="Fecha Creación";
$Vec_PARTEVBLE[20][3]="0";

$Vec_PARTEVBLE[21][0]="d_referencia_prov";
$Vec_PARTEVBLE[21][1]="";
$Vec_PARTEVBLE[21][2]="Referencia Prov.";
$Vec_PARTEVBLE[21][3]="0";

$Vec_PARTEVBLE[22][0]="pr_venta_actual";
$Vec_PARTEVBLE[22][1]="";
$Vec_PARTEVBLE[22][2]="Pr. Venta Actual";
$Vec_PARTEVBLE[22][3]="0";
```

Al único que quiero ponerle el formato es a `pr_Venta_Actual`

En mi formulario tengo lo siguiente:

```
if ($parte_vble > 0) {
    for ($k = 0; $k < $parte_vble; $k++) {
        if ($mat_datos[0][$i] == $Vec_PARTEVBLE[$k][0]) {
            if ($Vec_PARTEVBLE[$k][1] != "") {
                $inc_i = 2;
                $d_campo = $Vec_PARTEVBLE[$k][1];
            } else {
                $inc_i = 1;
            }
            $k = $parte_vble;
            $sw_total = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Lo que hice fue ponerlo de esta manera:

```
if ($parte_vble > 0) {
    for ($k = 0; $k < $parte_vble; $k++) {
        if ($mat_datos[0][$i] == $Vec_PARTEVBLE[$k][0]) {
            if ($Vec_PARTEVBLE[$k][1] != "") {
                $inc_i = 2;
                $d_campo = $Vec_PARTEVBLE[$k][1];
            } else {
                $inc_i = 1;
            }
            $k = $parte_vble;

            if ($d_campo = $Vec_PARTEVBLE[$k][25]) {
                $sw_total = 1;
            } else {
                $sw_total = 0;
            }

        }
    }
}


if ($inc_i == 1) {
    if ($sw_total == 1) {
        //echo "*-".$i.'-'.$mat_datos[$j][$i];
        //$dato = pimus_format($mat_datos[$j][$i],2,0);
        //var_dump($mat_datos);
        //echo "<br>decimal:<br>".$valorDecimal;
        $dato = number_format($mat_datos[$j][$i], $valorDecimal, $separadorDecimales, $separadorMiles);
    } else {
        $dato = $mat_datos[$j][$i];
    }
}
```

Comment: y porque no compruebas cuando vayas a imprimir el datos si el elemento $Vec_PARTEVBLE[ X ][0]  el igual a  "pr_venta_actual"? si es igual le aplicas el number_format y si no lo es lo muestras como sea

Comment: Genial, muchas.

Answer (score 1):

Se puede recorrer el array fila por fila. Cuando se encuentra el valor en `$a[0]`, se reemplaza el valor de `$a[3]`.

Para formatear el número con 2 decimales y separador de miles se usa [`number_format($valor, 2)`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php).

```php
foreach ($Vec_PARTEVBLE as &$fila) {
    if ($fila[0] == 'pr_venta_actual') {
        $fila[3] = number_format($fila[3], 2);
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Demo en ideone.com</kbd>](http://ideone.com/15p1vq)